# The programming storing quantities and writing else if statement to display the correct one

Tags: java

The program at the end will display the final estimation report. If the user only asked for one table, the output will display the final total estimate with the table as a singular. If the user asked for multiple tables, the output will display the number of tables and the total cost. If the user did not request any estimates at all, the program should display a message stating that.

It only displays "You did not estimate any tables...."

```java
public class Table {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String material;

        int tChoice;
        int mChoice;
        int numTable = 0;
        double tableCost;
        double total = 0;
        double pLaminate = 0.125;
        double pOak = 0.25;


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Tables are Us - Your One Stop Table Shop");
        System.out.println("Mike - Master Table Builder");

        boolean bFlag = true;

        while (bFlag) {
            double area = 0;
            double length = -1;
            double width = -1;
            double diameter = -1;
            double radius = -1;

            do {
                System.out.println("\n\nWhat shape of table do you wish to build?");
                System.out.println("\t1. Rectangular");
                System.out.println("\t2. Sqaure");
                System.out.println("\t3. Circular");
                System.out.println("\t4. End Program");
                System.out.print("Enter menu entry: ");

                tChoice = input.nextInt();

                if (tChoice < 1 || tChoice > 4) {
                    System.out.println("Error - Invalid Entry. Please reenter a valid value.");
                }

            } while (tChoice < 1 || tChoice > 4);

            if (tChoice == 1) {
                while (length < 0) {
                    System.out.print("Enter the length of the table (in inches): ");
                    length = input.nextDouble();

                    if (length < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Error - the length must be greater than zero. Please reenter!!");
                    }
                }

                while (width < 0) {
                    System.out.print("Enter the width of the table (in inches): ");
                    width = input.nextDouble();

                    if (width < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Error - the width must be greater than zero. Please reenter!!");
                    }
                }

                area = length * width;
            } else if (tChoice == 2) {
                while (length < 0) {

                    System.out.print("Enter the length of the table (in inches): ");

                    length = input.nextDouble();

                    if (length < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Error - the length must be greater than zero. Please reenter!!");
                    }
                }

                area = length * length;
            } else if (tChoice == 3) {
                while (diameter < 0) {
                    System.out.print("Enter the diameter of the table (in inches): ");
                    diameter = input.nextDouble();

                    if (diameter < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Error - the diameter must be greater than zero. Please reenter!!");
                    }
                }

                radius = diameter / 2;
                area = Math.PI * radius * radius;

            } else if (tChoice == 4) {
                if (numTable == 0) {
                    System.out.println("\nYou did not estimate any tables today!");
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("The total cost of the " + numTable + "tables you estimated is $" + String.format("%.2f", total));
                }


                System.out.println("Thank you for using the table cost estimation program!");
                System.out.println("GoodBye!!!");

                input.close();

                return;
            }

            do {
                System.out.println("\nWhat type of material do you want to use?");
                System.out.println("\t1. Laminate ($0.125 per square inch)");
                System.out.println("\t2. Oak ($0.25 per square inch)");
                System.out.print("Enter menu entry: ");

                mChoice = input.nextInt();

                if (mChoice < 1 || mChoice > 2) {

                    System.out.println("Error - Invalid Entry. Please reenter a valid value.");
                }

            } while (mChoice < 1 || mChoice > 2);


            if (mChoice == 1) {
                material = "Laminate";

                tableCost = area * pLaminate;
            } else {
                material = "Oak";

                tableCost = area * pOak;
            }

            System.out.println("\nOutput Report:");
            System.out.printf("The area of table is " + String.format("%.2f", area) + " square inches");
            System.out.printf("\nThe table will be made of " + material);
            System.out.printf("\nThe cost of the table is $" + String.format("%.2f", tableCost));

            total = total + tableCost;

            total++;

        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the full code and state what input you're passing to your program, what output you expect to have and what output you actually get. Also known as posting a [mre] with all the necessary information to help you with your problem. At a glance, if it only outputs that, then `tChoice` is 4 and `numTable` is 0, you might want to step through your program with a debugger if you expected those variables to hold other values to see where they incorrectly take them.

Comment: I have edited @JustAnotherDeveloper

Comment: at the end, if I did 1 or more tables, it should display total cost of the # tables you estimated is %#. instead of you did not estimate any tables today!

Comment: Yup, I noticed that. But... You don't ever set `numTable` to any value other than zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
        System.out.printf("The total cost of the %d tables you estimated is $%.2f%n", numTable, total);
```

Print-formatted needs a newline at the end `%n`.
Ensure that `numTable` is set.

Comment: @erigon88 It does work. At least the part about setting `numTable`. You initialize it to zero but never change its value. Therefore your code does what it's supposed to do when that variable is zero.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper what can i do to fix that

Comment: @erigon88 Why are you not incrementing `numTable` when you estimate a table, if you want `numTable` to hold the number of tables you have estimated? If you want a variable to have a value, you should set it to that value, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Table {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Tables are Us - Your One Stop Table Shop");
        System.out.println("Mike - Master Table Builder");

        int totalTables = 0;
        double totalTableCost = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        scan.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

        while (true) {
            int shapeMenuItem = getShapeMenuItem(scan);

            if (shapeMenuItem == 4) {
                printFinalResults(totalTables, totalTableCost);
                return;
            }

            double area = getArea(scan, shapeMenuItem);

            if (Double.isNaN(area))
                System.err.println("Error - Invalid Entry. Please reenter a valid value.");
            else {
                int materialMenuItem = getMaterialMenuItem(scan);
                double tableCost = area * getMaterialCost(materialMenuItem);

                totalTableCost += tableCost;
                totalTables++;

                printReport(area, tableCost, materialMenuItem);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printFinalResults(int numTable, double total) {
        if (numTable == 0)
            System.out.println("You did not estimate any tables today!");
        else
            System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "\nThe total cost of the %d tables you estimated is $%.2f\n", numTable, total);

        System.out.println("Thank you for using the table cost estimation program!");
        System.out.println("GoodBye!!!");
    }

    private static void printReport(double area, double tableCost, int materialMenuItem) {
        System.out.println("\nOutput Report:");
        System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "The area of table is %.2f square inches\n", area);
        System.out.println("The table will be made of " + getMaterialName(materialMenuItem));
        System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH, "The cost of the table is $%.2f\n", tableCost);
    }

    private static int getShapeMenuItem(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("\n\nWhat shape of table do you wish to build?");
        System.out.println("\t1. Rectangle");
        System.out.println("\t2. Square");
        System.out.println("\t3. Circle");
        System.out.println("\t4. End Program");
        System.out.print("Enter menu entry: ");

        return scan.nextInt();
    }

    private static int getMaterialMenuItem(Scanner scan) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("\nWhat type of material do you want to use?");
            System.out.println("\t1. Laminate ($0.125 per square inch)");
            System.out.println("\t2. Oak ($0.25 per square inch)");
            System.out.print("Enter menu entry: ");

            int menu = scan.nextInt();

            if (menu == 1 || menu == 2)
                return menu;

            System.err.println("Error - Invalid Entry. Please reenter a valid value.");
        }
    }

    private static double getArea(Scanner scan, int shapeMenuItem) {
        if (shapeMenuItem == 1)
            return getRectangleArea(scan);
        if (shapeMenuItem == 2)
            return getSquareArea(scan);
        if (shapeMenuItem == 3)
            return getCircleArea(scan);
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    private static double getRectangleArea(Scanner scan) {
        double length = readDouble(scan, "Enter the length of the table (in inches): ");
        double width = readDouble(scan, "Enter the width of the table (in inches): ");
        return length * width;
    }

    private static double getSquareArea(Scanner scan) {
        double length = readDouble(scan, "Enter the length of the table (in inches): ");
        return length * length;
    }

    private static double getCircleArea(Scanner scan) {
        double diameter = readDouble(scan, "Enter the diameter of the table (in inches): ");
        double radius = diameter / 2;
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

    private static String getMaterialName(int materialMenuItem) {
        if (materialMenuItem == 1)
            return "Laminate";
        if (materialMenuItem == 2)
            return "Oak";
        return null;
    }

    private static double getMaterialCost(int materialMenuItem) {
        if (materialMenuItem == 1)
            return 0.125;
        if (materialMenuItem == 2)
            return 0.25;
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    private static double readDouble(Scanner scan, String msg) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(msg);
            double val = scan.nextDouble();

            if (val > 0)
                return val;

            System.err.println("Error - Value must be greater than zero. Please reenter!!");
        }

    }
}
```